# Mail corruption in iPad

Tags: ipad, applications, email

My mail in iPad is acting terrible.  Many mails seem to have their contents and the header (sender, cc and subject) mixed up,  contents from one mail have the headers from another mail.  How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Often issues like this can be corrected by deleting the email account:

settings -> Mail, Contacts, Calendars -> [EMAIL ACCOUNT]

then scroll down and delete the account.

Then just re-add it. That usually works for me.